# How can I use netplan for DNS domains?

Tags: dns, netplan, dnsmasq

I am wondering if I actually *need* `dnsmasq` or `Bind` to apply the following simple DNS server rule:

Forward DNS lookups for *.mydomain.com to 10.0.0.2;

Forward DNS lookups for anything else to 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4

Or can I do that in a /etc/netplan/*.yaml file using the nameserver field somehow?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to configure systemd-resolved to do this, but not through netplan.  E.g. `systemd-resolve -i ens2 --set-dns=10.0.0.2 --set-domain=~mydomain.com`

You should also be able to configure this statically with a .network file; see `systemd.network(5)` for information.

Comment: I tried creating a _foo.network_ file in `/etc/systemd/network` and populating it simply with `[Network]\nDNS=10.0.0.2\nDomains=mydomain.com` but it didn't work.

Comment: You may need to make sure you apply a [Match] rule as well, and you also need to make sure the filename you use lexically sorts before 99-default.link, otherwise /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link will take precedence.  To be honest I have not used .network files like this myself however, so I only know the generalities of how it's supposed to work.